# Kafka with multi-listener configuration binding multiple IP addresses

Tags: ubuntu, apache-kafka

I have one Ubuntu 14 server which has two IP addresses (192.168.1.131 and 192.168.100.131).
Part of our team uses 192.168.1.131 to access the server and others use 192.168.100.131.

I want to run Kafka on the server. The `server.properties` are:

```
advertised.host.name = 192.168.1.131
```

With this configuration, we can access the Kafka service using the IP address 192.168.1.131. However, it does not work with IP address 192.168.100.131.

Is there a way to use Kafka on both interfaces that bind 192.168.1.131 and 192.168.100.131?

Answer (score 2):

in kafka 0.10.x,you can edit server.properties like this:

```
listeners=LINKER1://192.168.1.131:9091,LINKER2://101.200.213.131:9092

inter.broker.listener.name=LINKER2

# Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set, 
# it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value
# returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092

# Maps listener names to security protocols, the default is for them to be the same. See the config documentation for more details
listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL,LINKER1:PLAINTEXT,LINKER2:PLAINTEXT
```

Comment: That will put client traffic on one interface and inter-broker replication traffic on the other interface. I think the OP is looking for client traffic on both interfaces. I think that capability was also added recently (perhaps in 0.11) but I'm still trying to find where it's documented

Answer (score 0):

Multiple-listener configuration in Kafka has changed since this question was first asked. Both `advertised.host.name` and `advertised.port` are **deprecated** and were replaced by **`advertised.listeners`** (or **`KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS`** in case of Docker images).

In my opinion, this [blog post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/) by Confluent provides a good overview of various scenarios relating to Kafka listener configurations. In your specific case, I assume you want to have two listeners; one for each interface, binding 192.168.1.131 and 192.168.100.131.

The following broker configuration (`server.properties`) should achieve this:

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,INTF1://192.168.1.131:19092,INTF2://192.168.1.131:29092
listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,INTF1:PLAINTEXT,INTF2:PLAINTEXT
```

In case of Docker, you can use the following:

```
# ...
# Note that you also need to map the ports 19092 and 29092 accordingly
# ...
environment:
  # ...
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,INTF1://192.168.1.131:19092,INTF2://192.168.1.131:29092
  KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,INTF1:PLAINTEXT,INTF2:PLAINTEXT
# ...
```

For example, if clients connect to the broker on port 19092, they will get `192.168.1.131:19092` as a listener to connect to.

See also the blog post ["Kafka Listeners – Explained"](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/) by Confluent for more details.